# Why auto delete index policy doesn't work in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created a index policy in Kibana to delete index order than 7 days. Below is the configuration:

[image]

And I have indexes who are using this policy but none of them get deleted. Below is one of the index setting configuration. It has already specified the policy to use: `metrics-log-retention`. Is there anything I missed?

```json
{
  "aws-logs-2022-02-01" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "metrics-log-retention"
        },
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "aws-logs-2022-02-01",
        "creation_date" : "1643673636747",
        "priority" : "100",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "lLmO753nRpuw6bauKIJI2Q",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7150299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the hot phase. I have disabled all options under hot as shown in below screenshot. but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Below is the raw data for the index policy:

```json
{
  "metrics-log-retention" : {
    "version" : 4,
    "modified_date" : "2022-02-10T22:24:14.492Z",
    "policy" : {
      "phases" : {
        "hot" : {
          "min_age" : "0ms",
          "actions" : {
            "rollover" : {
              "max_size" : "50gb",
              "max_primary_shard_size" : "50gb",
              "max_age" : "1d"
            }
          }
        },
        "delete" : {
          "min_age" : "6d",
          "actions" : {
            "delete" : {
              "delete_searchable_snapshot" : true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "in_use_by" : {
      "indices" : [
        "aws-logs-2022-02-01",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-04",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-05",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-02",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-03",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-01",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-07",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-08",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-06",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-09",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-06",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-09",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-07",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-08",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-03",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-02",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-05",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-04",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-11",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-12",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-10",
        "aws-logs-2022-02-13",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-10",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-12",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-11",
        "aws-metrics-2022-02-13"
      ],
      "data_streams" : [ ],
      "composable_templates" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The creation date of that index is `Feb 2nd 2022` which is 6 days ago, and your policy would delete it after 7 days. Also can you show how your hot phase is configured?

Comment: sorry I manually deleted index order than 7 days. I added the screenshot of hot phase. I didn't configure anything, all is defaut value

Comment: Thanks, can you open "Advanced settings" so we can see the default hot phase retention?

Comment: The screenshot is for the advanced settings.

Comment: My bad, I didn't look correctly, let me add an answer

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the hot phase advanced settings, the default rollover settings are 30 days or 50GB, so your indexes will stay in the hot phase for 30 days, unless they grow over 50GB before.

Once the index gets out of the hot phase it gets into the delete phase and if you hover over the (i) icon, you can see that the 7 days are calculated AFTER the roll over from the hot phase.

[image: delete_phase]

So if you really want your indexes to be deleted after 7 days, you need to:

1. configure the hot phase to be shorter (say 6 days)
2. configure the delete phase to kick in after 1 day from rollover

That way, the index will be created and stay six days in the hot phase and then be deleted after one day.

Comment: I have disabled all settings in hot phase and updated the screenshot. But the index is not deleted. I have updated the json output in the question which I can see an index created 8 days ago.  Do I have to wait a few more days to see that? how often does the auto-delete job run?

Comment: No, you need to click on "Use recommended defaults" and change those defaults, which are 30 days or 50GB (you can even read that on the screenshot)

Comment: I updated the screenshot. I have disabled all default settings but still not delete the old index

Comment: You need to keep the "Enable rollover" switch active, otherwise nothing happens

Comment: I have enabled it but still not able to see it gets deleted. anything else I am missing?

Comment: You have 7 days in the hot phase rollover period

Comment: yes, 7 days which is same as deleted phase. Do you mean the auto delete happens in 7 days hot + 7 days delete = 14 days? In this case, I need to set the hot days to be 0?

Comment: I updated the screenshot to set 1 day in hot phase and 6 days in delete phase. but still nothing happens. Does ES show when the delete job is run?

Comment: I added the raw json data about the policy in the question. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to crontab on ES host, it will delete old indices automatically

```
0 7 * * * curl -u LOGIN:PASSWORD -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/aws-logs-$(date --date="7 days ago" +"%Y.%m.%d")
```